# find longest continuous array with values exceeding a threshold

Tags: arrays, matlab

How can I use 'find' in matlab to find the longest possible sequence of values that exceed a given threshold. Fro example, if I have:

```
X = [18 3 1 11 8 10 11 3 9 14 6 1 4 3 15 21 23 24];
```

and want to find the values that are larger than, say, 8, I would type:

```
find(X > 8)
```

However, I want to find where in the array is the longest continuous sequence of values larger than a given value. Here, the answer would be:

```
15 21 23 24
```

Is there a way to achieve this in matlab?

Comment: How is answer `15 21 23 24` obtained?

Comment: @LuisMendo, I think the key word is : "**the longest continuous sequence** of values larger than a given value"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let your data be defined as

```
X = [18 3 1 11 8 10 11 3 9 14 6 1 4 3 15 21 23 24]; %// input array
t = 8; %// threshold
```

#### Approach 1: using [`diff`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html)

```
Y = X>t; %// convert to zeros and ones
z = diff([false Y false]); %// compute changes. `false`s are needed to "close" the sequence
s = find(z>0); %// find indices of starts of runs
e = find(z<0)-1; %// find ends 
[~, w] = max(e-s); %// w is the index of the longest run
result_start = s(w); %// index of start of longest subsequence
result_end = e(w); %// index of end of longest subsequence
result_values = X(s(w):e(w)); %// values of longest subsequence
```

with the example `X` and `t`,

```
result_start =
    15
result_end =
    18
result_values =
    15    21    23    24
```

#### Approach 2: using [`regexp`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html)

```
Y = char(double(X>t) + '0'); %// convert to string of zeros and ones
[s, e] = regexp(Y, '1+', 'start', 'end'); %// find starts and ends of runs
[~, w] = max(e-s); %// w is the index of the longest run
result_start = s(w); %// index of start of longest subsequence
result_end = e(w); %// index of end of longest subsequence
result_values = X(s(w):e(w)); %// values of longest subsequence
```

The result is the same as above.

Comment: was just about to post the `diff` solution for those not comfortable with `regexp` ... good job !

Comment: @Hoki Thanks! It was my first thought, but I was initally lazy about it, because dealing with the initial and final values is complicated. I ended up doing it, with one `false` at the beginning and another at the end of the array. It's probably the preferred approach

Comment: ha ha ... tell me about it. I was too quick to use `diff` so at first attempt I ended up with: `idx = X>8;
didx = diff(idx) ;
s=find([idx(1) didx]== 1);
e=find([didx idx(end)*-1]==-1);` to reconcile the edge values. It works the same but it looked quite convoluted. _And by the time I came round to your version (which is definitively neater), yours was posted._

Comment: That `regexp` solution is ingenious.

Comment: @rayryeng It was an attempt to get avoid the edge cases of the `diff` approach. In the end I succumbed :-D