# Grouping data using loops (signal processing in MATLAB)

Tags: algorithm, matlab, for-loop, while-loop, signal-processing

I am working in MATLAB with a signal data that consist of consecutive dips as shown below. I am trying to write a code which sorts the contents of each dip into a separate group. How should the general structure of such a code look like?

The following is my data. I am only interested in the portion of the signal that lies below a certain threshold d (the red line):

[image: Signal]

And here is the desired grouping:

[image: Grouping]

Here is an unsuccessful attempt:

```
k=0; % Group number

for i = 1 : length(signal)
    if signal(i) < d
        k=k+1;
        while signal(i) < d
            NewSignal(i, k) = signal(i);
            i = i + 1; 
        end
    end
end
```

The code above generated 310 groups instead of the desired 12 groups.

Any explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please elaborate, on what do you mean with "groups"? Obviously, you have continuous data. So, do you want, for example, a cell array or struct (with 12 entries), storing all `(t, y)` data per "group"? Cell array or struct, because I assume, the number of data points per "group" may vary.

Comment: Why dont you creat a logical array through comparison against your threshold. Search for all the subsequences in this array (consecutive indexes ), and there you go you have your groups.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32439805/find-longest-continuous-array-with-values-exceeding-a-threshold) searches for the longest continues array above a threshold. To adjust this code to search for all arrays (in your case below a threshold) should be very easy

Comment: @CrisLuengo No. I examined my data carefully. The data points within the dips do not fluctuate above the threshold. The problem must be related to the way my loops are written.

Comment: @Irreducible Thanks a lot for the link. The example using regexp works for my data. But the problem is that, in each run the code finds the dip with the most amount of elements in it. Do you know how to modify the code so that it will group the dips sequentially? For example, I want to assign the elements of dip 1 into group 1, elements of dip 2 into group 2, etc.

Comment: Yes instead taking the indexes which have the most Element just take all the start and ends from the regexp, each pair is a group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking Benl generated data you can do the following:

```
%generate data
x=1:1000;
y=sin(x/20);
for ii=1:9
    y=y+-10*exp(-(x-ii*100).^2./10);
end
y=awgn(y,4);


%set threshold
t=-4;
%threshold data
Y = char(double(y<t) + '0'); %// convert to string of zeros and ones
%search for start and ends
```

This idea is taken [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32439805/find-longest-continuous-array-with-values-exceeding-a-threshold)

```
[s, e] = regexp(Y, '1+', 'start', 'end');

%and now plot and see that each pair of starts and end
% represents a group
plot(x,y)
hold on
for k=1:numel(s)
line(s(k)*ones(2,1),ylim,'Color','k','LineStyle','--')
line(e(k)*ones(2,1),ylim,'Color','k','LineStyle','-')
end
hold off
legend('Data','Starts','Ends')
```

[image: Processed Data]

Comments: First of all I choose an arbitrary threshold, it is up to you to find the "best" one in your data. Additionally I didn't group the data explicitly but rather this approach gives you the start and end of each epoch with a dip (you might call it group). So you could say that each index is the grouping index. Finally I did not debug this approach for corner cases, when dips fall on starts and ends...

Comment: I managed to use this approach, but I had to smooth the data a little. In general the problem is that in the original data it often finds more than one subsequence per dip. I mean, once the code identifies the largest strings from all dips, it continues to find smaller strings from the previously identified dips. Is there any way to tweak the code so that we still get one set of data per dip (without smoothing)? What would be a good way to tell the program to ignore strings from the vicinity of the previously registered regions?

Comment: My first thought would be that it is related to the threshold, however, not knowing your data and how exactly you implemented the code in your case makes it difficult to suggest anything meaningful. I would suggest you open up a new question with your code, best case some example dataset, and show us the desired and received result.

Answer (score 1):

In MATLAB you cannot change the loop index of a `for` loop. A for loop:

```
for i = array
```

loops over each column of `array` in turn. In your code, `1 : length(signal)` is an array, each of its elements is visited in turn. Inside this loop there is a while loop that increments `i`. However, when this while loop ends and the next iteration of the for loop runs, `i` is reset to the next item in the array.

This code therefore needs two `while` loops:

```matlab
i = 1; % Index
k = 0; % Group number
while i <= numel(signal)
    if signal(i) < d
        k = k + 1;
        while signal(i) < d
            NewSignal(i,k) = signal(i);
            i = i + 1; 
        end
    end
    i = i + 1;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy, the function you're looking for is `bwlabel`, which when combined with logical indexing makes this simple.

To start I made some fake data which resembled your data

```
x=1:1000;
y=sin(x/20);
for ii=1:9
    y=y+-10*exp(-(x-ii*100).^2./10);
end
y=awgn(y,4);
plot(x,y)
```

[image]

Then set your threshold and use 'bwlabel'

```
d=-4;% set the threshold

groupid=bwlabel(y<d);
```

`bwlabel` labels connected groups in a black and white image, what we've effectively done here is make a black and white (logical 0 & 1) 1D image in the logical vector `y<d`. `bwlabel` returns the number of the region at the index of the region. We're not interested in the 0 region, so to get the x values or y values of the nth region, simply use `x(groupid==n)`, for example with my test data

```
x_4=x(groupid==4)
y_4=y(groupid==4)

x_4 = 398   399   400   401   402
y_4 = -5.5601   -7.8280   -9.1965   -7.9083   -5.8751
```

Comment: Hi there, this is a very interesting approach. But when I apply it to my data, in some cases, the elements of one dip are stored in more than one group. I got 20 groups, instead of the required 12.